# BigQuery error: Cannot partition on repeated field

Tags: google-bigquery

I have two tables `table1` (complex one with repeated/record columns) and `table2` (fairly simple). I am trying to create a new table with all columns from `table1` with one column from `table2` using the following query:

```
select t1.id, t1.experience.desc, t1.experience.organization.*, t1.experience.department, t2.field2 as t1.experience.organization.newfield, t1.family_name
from [so_public.table1] as t1 left join each [so_public.table2] as t2
on t1.experience.organization.name = t2.field1
```

I get an error **Cannot partition on repeated field** as shown in the image below. The schemas of the two tables are also shown in their respective images.

Is there a general rule of thumb here when one wants to merge data from two tables? Is what I am trying to do at all possible?

The actual tables are much more complex. I am only showing enough context that reproduces the issue.

[image: Query with error]
[image: Table1 schema]
[image: Table2 schema]

Answer (score 6):

You will need to FLATTEN() your tables before joining them.

This doesn't work:

```
SELECT a.fullName, b.fullname
FROM [bigquery-samples:nested.persons_living] a
JOIN [bigquery-samples:nested.persons_living] b
ON a.citiesLived.place=b.citiesLived.place
LIMIT 1000

Error: Cannot join on repeated field citiesLived.place
```

This does:

```
SELECT a.fullName, b.fullname
FROM FLATTEN([bigquery-samples:nested.persons_living], citiesLived) a
JOIN FLATTEN([bigquery-samples:nested.persons_living], citiesLived) b
ON a.citiesLived.place=b.citiesLived.place
LIMIT 1000
```

Comment: Is it at all possible for you to rewrite my query? I tried but I failed. I am either getting errors or unexpected results.

Comment: @wpfwannabe, if you make a sample dataset public, I can re-write the query and test it before publishing

Comment: Please see edited question. The query should now reference a public dataset. Please note that what I am really after is original table + some columns from the other joined table (not just flattened results).

Answer (score 1):

With the public sample you published on edit, a working query:

```
select t1.id, t1.experience.desc, t1.experience.department, t1.experience.organization.*, t2.field2 as t1.experience.organization.newfield, t1.family_name
from FLATTEN(FLATTEN([earnest-stock-91916:so_public.table1], experience.organization), experience) as t1 left join each [earnest-stock-91916:so_public.table2] as t2
on t1.experience.organization.name = t2.field1;
```

I was able to FLATTEN the data (had to apply it twice), but not to recover the original structure - joining against one of the sub-rows is harder.

I see what you want to do is enrich some of the sub-rows?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am trying to do. I want to use the original data/schema and create a **new** table with additional columns (richer schema). So far I have not been able to do this. It seems impossible. In order to do this I would have to do the schema expansion in the data preparation phase - before I actually import into BQ. Sounds terrible.